# Golang: Trying to create a name, age tuple with zip functionality similar to python

Tags: python, go

I have two data elements like

```
"bob julie mark mike"
```

And

```
"20,30,40,50"
```

And I split them, now I am trying to achieve to return a python:zip type result something like below

```
[("bob", "20"), ("julie", "30"), ("mark", "40"), ("mike", "50)]
```

I have tried with below code, but I am getting error `unexpected comma, expecting )` at line `namesAgesTuple[index] = stringTuple[(value, b[index])]`

below is complete code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type stringTuple struct {
    names string
    ages  string
}

func main() {
    var names string = "bob julie mark mike"
    namesArray := strings.Split(names, " ")
    fmt.Println(namesArray)

    var ages string = "20,30,40,50"
    agesArray := strings.Split(ages, ",")
    fmt.Println(agesArray)

    namesAges := make(map[string]string)

    println(len(namesArray))
    println(len(agesArray))
    print(namesAges)

    fmt.Println(zip(namesArray, agesArray))

}

func zip(a []string, b []string) ([]stringTuple, error) {

    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("zip: arguments length must be same ")
    }

    namesAgesTuple := make(map[int][]stringTuple)

    for index, value := range a {
        namesAgesTuple[index] = stringTuple[(value, b[index])]
    }
    fmt.Println(namesAgesTuple)
    return namesAgesTuple, nil

}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: which problem are you trying to solve with this datastructure? in go, you have map for mapping e.g. names to ages, and you have struct for storing name and age together (both of which you already use) - and you can also make a slice of these name-age structs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go doesn't have tuple syntax, perhaps you want something like:

```
stringTuple{value, b[index]}
```

Since `stringTuple` is a struct, this is initializing its fields; you could also provide field names explicitly as in:

```
stringTuple{names: value, ages: b[index]}
```

Another problem in your code is that `namesAgesTuple` is a map from `int` to a slice of `stringTuple`. But the function just returns a slice, so I'm not sure why you're using a map there.

I'd probably write the code something like this ([Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/cIygL89KlX-)):

```
type stringTuple struct {
    names string
    ages  string
}

func main() {
    var names string = "bob julie mark mike"
    namesArray := strings.Split(names, " ")
    fmt.Println(namesArray)

    var ages string = "20,30,40,50"
    agesArray := strings.Split(ages, ",")
    fmt.Println(agesArray)

    fmt.Println(zip(namesArray, agesArray))
}

func zip(a []string, b []string) ([]stringTuple, error) {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("zip: arguments length must be same ")
    }

    var namesAges []stringTuple
    for index, value := range a {
        namesAges = append(namesAges, stringTuple{value, b[index]})
    }
    return namesAges, nil
}
```